# Prove that $n=a^2+b^2-c^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any natural number $n$ prove that there exist natural numbers $a,b,c$ for which $$n=a^2+b^2-c^2.$$

I think we can have a proof by induction because :

If $n=0$ we choose $a=b=c=0$ or $a=0,b=c$.

If $n=1$ we choose $a=1,b=c$.

Now we need to prove the relationship holds for $n+1$ but I can't prove that.

Comment: General comment : in an induction proof, the hard step is usually the induction step, not the first step. So you shouldn't believe you have an induction proof just because you barely worked to work out the inductive step. Otherwise you could have proved "by induction" the opposite of Fermat's Last Theorem (because it is "true" when the exponent is $1$ or $2$).

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is odd, say $2k+1$, let $a=k+1$, $c=k$, $b=0$. If $n$ is even, let $b=1$ and goto $n$ odd.